# How long time usually application is given to finish in background (backgroundTimeRemaining)

Tags: ios

I need to get user location update when application is in background. I used "significant change feature" but the problem with significant change it's not accurate.

Hence, to  improve accuracy of  "significant change" a "little bit" I'm thinking to complement this with `UIApplication:beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`.

Thus, my question is how long usually application is given (the value in `backgroundTimeRemaining`) to run in background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently (as of iOS 5), the maximum time an app can remain in the background to finish tasks is 10 minutes. This can change in future iOS releases. You can check the value for yourself by logging the return value of `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]` when your app enters the background.

Comment: Im running a loop and [[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining] returns negative numbers when the 10min are up. Is this because Im running as developer? would the app be terminated by now in the real world? (Im running a standard apple dev environment)

Comment: Is there a way to extend or refresh that 10 minutes?

Comment: The [release notes of iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-7.0/) indicate that the time an application is given to complete a background task has been reduced significantly since iOS 7. The time interval mentioned in the accepted answer (ten minutes) is no longer valid for iOS 7+.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 7 and later the background task time is around 3 min